# Removing Nodes for XML using XSLT - Don't need CRLF against removed nodes/fields

Tags: xslt

I am using following XSLT to remove empty nodes from the XML. It is working fine by removing the empty nodes but it is also adding CRLF in place of removed nodes.

```
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
  <xsl:template match="*[not(child::node())]"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

[image: Extra CRLFs]

I don't need these CRLFs. Please suggest!

Comment: use `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` and add `indent="yes"` in `xsl:output`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not *adding* anything, but it is also not *removing* the left over whitespace text nodes between the elements in the original XML.  If your XML has no mixed content then the simplest approach is to remove *all* the whitespace-only text nodes and then re-indent the result tree:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" />
```

If you need to preserve the indentation from the original XML then you need to be slightly more creative

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(child::node())]"/>
<xsl:template match="text()[not(normalize-space())]
               [preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::*][not(child::node())]]" />
```

The second template will squash whitespace-only text nodes that immediately follow an element that has been squashed by the first template.

Answer (score 1):

It might simply be that e.g.

```
<root>
  <foo></foo>
  <foo>2</foo>
</root>
```

results in

```
<root>

  <foo>2</foo>
</root>
```

as your code removes the element but not any preceding or trailing white space text node.

In many cases simply doing

```
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

avoids the problem and gives you nice and consistent indentation.

Or you need to write templates ensuring that a white space text node before or after an empty element is removed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Other solution which worked for me was by using translate. Below is the XSLT:

```
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
  <xsl:template match="*[not(child::node())]"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '&#10;&#13;', '')"/>
  </xsl:template>
```